# Issue with GeoServer login with SSL

Tags: tomcat, centos, geoserver

I have a tomcat apache installed with ssl on Centos and I have deployed GeoServer as webapp into tomcat…when I access GeoServer through tomcat as
https://XXXX.XXXXXXXXX.com/geoserver/web/
and enter the login details page will be redirected to http://localhost:8080/geoserver/j_spring_security_check,it supposed to take me inside GeoServer again with https link

Comment: did you set the proxy url on the global page?

Comment: I am struggling in home page ,unable to login because of the error .So I cannot access the global page..

Comment: you should still be able to login in via `http://localhost:8080` but the answer you posted works as well

Comment: no ,I have installed the geoserver on online host server.

Comment: then I'd use an SSH tunnel

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After 3 days ,finally I figured out the issue.
You have to do the below steps to make it work :

1. Go to the geoserver directory inside apatche/webapps
2. Open the web.xml file inside web-inf for editing
3. Uncomment the below tag and edit the value to you tomcat main url as
   below :

```
    <context-param>
      <param-name>PROXY_BASE_URL</param-name>
      <param-value>https://XXXXX.XXXXXXXXXX.XXXX/geoserver</param-value>
      </context-param>
```

4. Save the file and everything works.

Comment: Don't forget to correct the wrongly written end tag </paramvalue> to </param-value>

Answer (score 11):

This problem can be solved with JVM parameter `-DALLOW_ENV_PARAMETRIZATION=true` and environment variable `PROXY_BASE_URL=https://XXXXX.XXXXXXXXXX.XXXX/geoserver`.

Tested on kartoza/geoserver:2.20.1 (snippet from docker-compose.yml):

```
environment:
  - JAVA_OPTS="-DALLOW_ENV_PARAMETRIZATION=true"
  - PROXY_BASE_URL=https://XXXXX.XXXXXXXXXX.XXXX/geoserver
```